# How to change a dataframe in R where you have multiple columns to just one column

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a data frame like this a

```
x <- data.frame("Name" = c("John","Dora"),"SN" = 1:2,"SN_1" = 7:8,"SN_2" = 5:6 )
```

```
  Name SN SN_1 SN_2
1 John  1    7    5
2 Dora  2    8    6
```

And I want to transform it to:

```
  Name SN
1 John  1
2 Dora  2
3 John  7
4 Dora  8
5 John  5
6 Dora  6
```

Comment: Have a look at `pivot_longer()` https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pivot_longer

Comment: Or use `reshape2::melt(x)`

Comment: better use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` as `reshape2` is retired

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)
melt(x,
    id.vars = "Name",
    measure.vars = patterns(c("SN")))[,.(Name, SN = value)]
```